# Error while exporting data from dynamodb to s3 using Amazon data pipeline

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-data-pipeline

I'm trying to use Data pipeline service to export data from dynamodb to S3 but keep getting the following error.

> Unable to create resource for @EmrClusterForBackup_ due to: 
>       The supplied ami version is invalid. 
>       (Service: AmazonElasticMapReduce; Status Code: 400; Error Code: ValidationException; Request ID: xxx)

I have tried changing AMI to a lot of different values according to their documentation like all the ones in `4.x.x` and `5.x.x` series but keep getting the same error. I see there have been few threads but none have an answer.
Hoping to find someone who's been able to solve this.

Comment: I hope you're adding the AMI id given to you

Comment: @AakashVerma Can you specify what given means? By default, the AMI was 3.9 which didn't seem to work and hence I tried these different combinations.

Comment: Please post the connection command where you're facing this error.

Comment: In the event that this is a backup process, it may be relevant that backup and restore is now offered natively through [DynamoDB backup](https://aws.amazon.com/dynamodb/backup-restore/)

Comment: I tried using the backup option but apparently, it's not yet available for my account. All I see is 'this feature will be coming to your account'. So I used Hive to do the job.

Answer (score 4):

Check if region of your EMR Cluster is the same as region of pipeline. 
There is a bug and by default it is set as region of DynamoDB (which might be different)

Comment: Gnarly bug - thanks for answering!  The default DynamoDB => S3 config that Amazon generates uses the dynamodb region for the resource, but you need to use the region of the data pipeline itself.  In my case, they were different as AWS Data Pipelines isn't available in all regions.

Comment: I was very frustrated with this, given that datapipelines only work in special regions it shouldn't put an automatic region without checking first if it is available.  Kudos!.